# Can I left-align desktop images on OS X Mavericks

Tags: desktop, osx-mavericks

OS X Mavericks has a few alignment options for desktop images. However, none serve my purpose. I would like to use a relatively thin image as a desktop background (e.g., a scroll), and I would like it to be right-aligned on my desktop, so that most of the desktop is simply the background color selected in the system preferences.

As a workaround, I can create a larger image the size of my desktop and copy the desired, thin image to its right edge. But this is a clumsy fix, and it'd be great if there was something better.

Thanks.

Comment: You've more than likely found that easiest possible workaround. Your only other option is probably third party software.

Answer (score -1):

While unclear of what you want to achieve, I explain some of the design concepts of Mac OS X below.

Apple prefers important things to be on the right hand side (for example, the "Save" button, "OK" button, the disk icon, etc), as the designer thinks that there is a **shorter distance** for people to move their mouse cursor to the important things, by assuming most people use their mouse with right hand.

While Microsoft thinks the reverse. The company thinks people may accidentally clicks the decisive buttons, so they put things on the **left**.